Formalize probability statements
There are a bunch of probability problems stated like:

Let R.V. $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, and R.V. $Y$ uniformly distributed on $[X, 1]$, what is $\mathbb{E}[Y]$? (Answer: $\frac{3}{4}$)
Let R.V.s $X_k$ be i.i.d., find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, where $Y:=X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N$ and $N$ is random index of some distribution. (Answer: $\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X_1]$)

How to define such problems rigorously (in the language of measure theory)?
For example, in problem 1, $X$ is measurable map from $\Omega \to [0, 1]$, what about $Y$? What does it mean for an interval to have a random variable as the starting point?
In problem 2, what does it mean to add up a random number of R.V. in the first place? What's the underlying probability space of Y when taking the expectation? I guess maybe we can construct a product probability space of the underlying sample spaces of $X_k$ and $N$, and $Y$ is a measurable map from that product space to say $\mathbb{R}$.

See the first few pages of chapter 5 of Probability Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett where how to construct such random variables is discussed. (Or really any book that discusses Markov processes).

Note, there isn't one such answer. The conditions state a condition not on $\Omega,$ and there can be lots of fundamentally different  examples,but we can give examples. In the first case, we can take $\Omega=(0,1]^2$ with the standard measure and  selecting $(s,t)\in\Omega$ gives $(X,Y)=(s,s+(1-s)t).$

Quite often, you can define $\Omega$ in terms of a product the spaces for independent variables. For the first example, $Y$ is not an independent variable, so we invent a $Z=t$ independent from $X$ with $Y=X+(1-X)Z.$

For the second, you need $N$ independent from the $X_i.$ You can then use $\Omega=\mathbb N\times[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ but the measure is messier on this space.

@ThomasAndrews Ah I understand your explanation for the first case. Could you please post an answer on how to write a rigorous answer for the second one? How does $\Omega:= \mathbb{N} \times [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ help?
